# How to recover local repository after PC crash?

Tags: git

I encountered a Windows blue screen while refreshing gitk history tool after a checkout. Once my PC rebooted, my local repo was completely messed up. Any git command leads to the following error message:

```
error: unable to unpack c6424c31a54e292669cfdcba3136e7962c690437 header
error: inflateEnd: stream consistency error (no message)
fatal: loose object c6424c31a54e292669cfdcba3136e7962c690437 (stored in .git/objects/c6/424c31a54e292669cfdcba3136e7962c690437) is corrupt
```

The referenced file is full of 0's. Following misc posts about recovering a local repo, I ran `git fsck`, which leads to the same error output. After a backup of the .git directory, I removed the corrupted file and re-ran `git fsck` many times (removing the corrupted files one after the other) until I got the following output:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (38484/38484), done.
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer c6424c31a54e292669cfdcba3136e7962c690437
error: refs/heads/CSS does not point to a valid object!
error: 8a91e61fae289397ca2668a3971199dc1596decf: invalid sha1 pointer in cache-tree
error: a21652baded5946d40820d716b14ab86008889e8: invalid sha1 pointer in cache-tree
broken link from    tree 770bb33eb5f833e57562a2f1d9a4c23da0865b16
              to    tree 8a91e61fae289397ca2668a3971199dc1596decf
broken link from    tree 770bb33eb5f833e57562a2f1d9a4c23da0865b16
              to    tree a21652baded5946d40820d716b14ab86008889e8
dangling commit <sha1> <many times>
dangling blob <sha1> <many times>
missing tree 8a91e61fae289397ca2668a3971199dc1596decf
missing tree a21652baded5946d40820d716b14ab86008889e8
```

The missing tree sha1 both correspond to a corrupted file I removed earlier.

`c6424c31` is also one of the corrupted files I removed, and refs/heads/CSS is the current branch.

`git ls-tree` for `770bb33e` returns the root directory of my project. `git ls-tree` for the missing trees of course returns `not a tree object`. I have no clue about the corrupted file or commit.

I cannot checkout to another branch or master because git tells me there are local changes (which I cannot commit or reset).

I suppose I definitively lost some data, but would like to recover as much as possible from that local repository : it contains some committed data that was not pushed yet, and hope to find it somewhere in the internal structure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be a workaround but maybe it works for you:

- look for local changes. I think the command "git status" will do this.
- copy/backup those files from your file system.
- recreate your local repository from scratch and pull the latest changes from origin.
- overwrite the backed up files on your file system.
- now commit your changes.

Comment: `git status` throws "fatal: bad object HEAD". Further, the changes I want to recover are not on the currently checked out branch, but on another local branch I cannot checkout.Thanks anyway for your help.